# Unable to set firewall to prevent traffic to 8080 on a GCE Instance

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, google-compute-engine

We are trying to prevent a VM on GCE from replying to requests on port 8080.
Have set-up the following firewall -

[Firewall to prevent the machine from replying to requests on port 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOcRY.png)

However I can still access the port and the application on port 8080. I tried changing the priority of this rule to 1 but to no avail.

Any pointers in what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Same discussion is taking place in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/5efz9c5wPik)

Comment: Yes I asked it there as well. Since the community replied there I would request anybody who has questions on this follow that thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in this Google Groups [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/5efz9c5wPik), the firewall will block Egress traffic from the instance, if it is initiated there. Per this Google Cloud [article](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#egress_cases), “ Egress deny rules prevent instances from initiating connections that match non-permitted port, protocol, and IP range combinations.”

In order to prevent the VM from replying to requests, assuming that ingress traffic is allowed, you have to modify the VM’s firewall itself. If you are using a Linux OS you may check this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/) about modifying iptables. This could be a workaround, but it is not recommended.

The best approach, in order for the VM to behave properly, is to deny Ingress traffic on that port by using the GCP firewall. Hence, blocking these requests from reaching the VM’s OS. “While firewall rules are applied to the network as a whole, connections are allowed or denied at the instance level” [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls). Note that when creating firewall rules in GCP, referring to Ingress or Egress is from the point of view of the VM itself and not the GCP firewall.